# Finding facilities on current direction for Network Analyst result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

We use ArcGIS Network Analyst to solve routing problems.

We received a request about filtering facilities (point feature class) along the route result. Also the direction should match. The facilities on the other side of the road should not be displayed.

How can we do it with or without post processing?

Answer (score 1):

We decided to use offset and nearestCoordinate functions of the ArcGIS Javascript API to solve this problem.

First we calculate offset version of the geometry which we got from Network Analyst with a positive value (5 meters for example). Then, for each point we want to determine its side, we execute nearestCoordinate function against original geometry and offset version. Finally we compare distance attributes. If original distance is smaller then point is on the left side of the road, othwerwise it's on the right.

We could solve this with buffer tool with sideType parameter set to right. But this feature is not included in ArcGIS Javascript API.